# Any code to integrate paypal in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: paypal, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am developing my first website e-commerce with Visual Studio 2022 and ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. Could someone share with me some code in order to integrate Paypal payments for this version of website?

PS: also, if there is any tutorial that you advise me in order to follow and develop my first e-commerce with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.

Thanks

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Comment: If you are looking for a guide that walks you through how to get payments and provides an example of a well-working integration with PayPal, look at the demo --> https://techtolia.com/PayPal/

Answer (score 0):

PayPal website says to use Braintree. Here is the link to the tutorial for you: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/start/hello-server/dotnet

Comment: Hi, what is Braintree? it is part of paypal API? any example of working code for C#? thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone share with me some code in order to integrate Paypal payments for this version of website?

For Paypal integration you should attach it with your order in that
case you can Call the v2/checkout/orders API directly. Here are the URL.

### Endpoints For v2 Orders API

Server-side create: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create

Server-side capture: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture

### Understand how it works

Here you could have a look how to implement [implements on the order page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal#add-paypal-class-and-api-credentials). So that it will be easier for you to understand. You just need to call a few APIs.

### Paypal Integration Guides

I would suggest to follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for the 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately
*before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

### .Net server-side SDK

You can get the SDK sample here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK

(using this `SDK` is optional, `direct HTTPS API` calls first using a clientid+secret to obtain an access token are also possible.  In any case, do not use the deprecated PayPal-NET-SDK which is for the old v1/payments API)

### Note

While you would be working on implementation, if you encounter any specific issue feel free to post that. That will be more convenient to assist you on this. First, try to implement within your application.

Comment: Hi, i can see the CURL examples.. i was actually looking for C# asp.net example, where to find it?

Comment: In that case post another question for that. So that a example can be written using CURL as this question about PayPal integration guideline.